# How to use Putty to connect to a virtual machine?

Tags: putty

I am running a virtual machine on Virtual Box

On running `ifconfig eth1`, I get
inet addr: 192.168.56.11 and many more values.

How do I use Putty (ssh) here? 
I entered 192.168.56.11 on the Host Name and 80 on the Port Number, but Putty can't connect.

I am trying to follow the guidelines from this course:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cs144-misc/instructions/vm.html

What exactly does Putty do? I don't understand why I need to do this.

Comment: Later versions of Windows 10 have a native ssh client (openssh port).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PuTTY will open a "network" between both machines. You'll get a console (like the shell) when you'll be connected. Really useful to administrate remote server from your computer.

Usually, the port is not 80, but 22.

Comment: Port: 22, sorry. Sometimes 21. Depending on the way you connect.

Comment: It's because you're using a SSH tunnel. ;)

Comment: Please close the question if you got your answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

For oracle vm virtual box:

1)Power of your machine

2)goto Settings -> Network -> Adapter1 -> Enable Network Adapter -> select "Bridge Adapter" in Attache To tab and   click 'ok" button

3) open terminal in virtual box and type" ifconfig"

in first paragraph

eth0              Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:fb:d1:28
          inet addr:172.16.2.199

4) Here ip address is "172.16.2.199"   using this ip and port 22 ,you can login through putty and winscp also

Answer (score 2):

Try opening terminal through VMWare's console on Ubuntu and then run below given code:

sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.

**Note:** I assume you have already started the VM, importing the ISO image, and tried to access the machine with 10.X.X.X or 172.X.X.X range IP address from the Putty agent and got an time-out message.

Before making any changes to the network configuration on the VM or trying bridge-adapters, as suggested by many of the articles online, I suggest you to check 2 robust points which forms the bus for your VM on VirtualBox and Putty agent installed on your system.

1st Point:

[Opening Host Network Manager in File section of your Oracle VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOJtQ.png)

[Adding a host-only ethernet network (I suggest to keep a 192.X.X.X range)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLQEm.png)

2nd Point: Adding a host-only adapter, under the network settings of your VM.

[Host-Only Adapter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWfhT.png)

If you follow these steps before booting up the VM for the first time, your VM will be allocated with a 192 range IP address (by the dhcp) the moment it boots up and starts running. Now all you need to do is, install and openssh-server and use the 192-range IP address with the Putty agent and Voila!!

Hope this help! Greetings!